# Doctrine OneToOne drives me crazy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I know that is a recurrent question but after creating a OneToOne relation between 2 entities and run 'php app/console doctrine:schema:validate' I get this error:

```
'[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'HO\CisBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts' mapping is invalid:
* The association HO\CisBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts#affiliate refers to the inverse side field HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity\Affiliate#affiliateSalesAccounts which does not exist.'
```

This is part of the code with both entities:

AffiliatesSalesAccount Entity

```
namespace HO\CisBundle\Entity;

use HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity\Affiliate;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="AffiliateSalesAccounts")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class AffiliateSalesAccounts {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity\Affiliate
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity\Affiliate", inversedBy="affiliateSalesAccounts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="affiliate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    private $affiliate;

    ...

    /**
     * @param Affiliate $affiliate
     */
    public function setAffiliate(Affiliate $affiliate)
    {
        $this->affiliate = $affiliate;
    }

    /**
     * @return Affiliate
     */
    public function getAffiliate()
    {
        return $this->affiliate;
    }
}
```

Affiliate Entity

```
namespace HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity;

use HO\CisBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ho_Affiliate")
 */
class Affiliate
{


    /**
     * @var AffiliateSalesAccounts
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="HO\CisBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts", mappedBy="affiliate")
     */
    private $affiliateSalesAccounts;


    ....

    /**
     * @param \HO\CisBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts $affiliateSalesAccounts
     */
    public function setAffiliateSalesAccounts($affiliateSalesAccounts)
    {
        $this->affiliateSalesAccounts = $affiliateSalesAccounts;
    }

    /**
     * @return \HO\CisBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts
     */
    public function getAffiliateSalesAccounts()
    {
        return $this->affiliateSalesAccounts;
    }

}
```

I have other similar OneToOne relations between 2 entities and it works great.

Someone can I help me?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Try changing your `targetEntity` attributes to `targetEntity="\HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity\Affiliate"` and `targetEntity="\HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts"`, respectively. Note the preceding backwards slash to ensure the namespace is correct.

Comment: @sjagr, it doesn't work, all the references to entities work perfectly without this slash

Comment: Consider adding  * @ORM\Entity() to your Affiliate entity.

Comment: @Cerad, no luck, I realized of that before, I added @ORM\Entity() annotation and nothing, same behavior with/without this annotation. I clean cache every time I make changes

Comment: Do you happen to have some metadata caching in place? Maybe try restarting the webserver?

Comment: Then take a look under Resources/config/doctrine and delete any yml/xml files you might find there.  And update your question to reflect your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem... First, sorry for bothering you because it was a stupid silly absent-mindedness... Since we use Redis to cache doctrine (with sncRedisBundle), specially metadata and query, Affiliate entity was cached in Redis but without the new field declaration "affiliateSalesAccounts". After deleting the key which store Affiliate entity the problem was solved.

Thank so much for your comments

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your problem but I notice that I do it in a different way I just let the code here so that you will be able to check it

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
 **/
private $profile;
```

The other class:

```
/**
 * @var \Lifecrops\LCUserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Lifecrops\LCUserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ussually I do something like this:

```
namespace HO\CisBundle\Entity;

use HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity\Affiliate;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="AffiliateSalesAccounts")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AffiliateSalesAccounts {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Affiliate", inversedBy="affiliateSalesAccounts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="affiliate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    private $affiliate;

    /**
     * @param Affiliate $affiliate
     */
    public function setAffiliate(Affiliate $affiliate)
    {
        $this->affiliate = $affiliate;
    }

    /**
     * @return Affiliate
     */
    public function getAffiliate()
    {
        return $this->affiliate;
    }
}
```

And the second entity:

```
namespace HO\HasoffersBundle\Entity;

use HO\CisBundle\Entity\AffiliateSalesAccounts;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ho_Affiliate")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Affiliate
{


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AffiliateSalesAccounts", mappedBy="affiliate")
     */
    private $affiliateSalesAccounts;

    /**
     * @param AffiliateSalesAccounts $affiliateSalesAccounts
     */
    public function setAffiliateSalesAccounts($affiliateSalesAccounts)
    {
        $this->affiliateSalesAccounts = $affiliateSalesAccounts;
    }

    /**
     * @return AffiliateSalesAccounts
     */
    public function getAffiliateSalesAccounts()
    {
        return $this->affiliateSalesAccounts;
    }

}
```

Clearing cache is imortant part, and if all goes bad you can look to:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    auto_mapping: true
```